# How do I get Rails Active Record Association question text to show with empty answer fields in nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-loops

I'm using Rails 6 and I have a form with several interview questions (14). The interview answers belong to a story and a story_question. The answers are submitted with the story as a nested form_for field. This part works fine. I'm having a hard time getting the story questions to display for each story answer text field. Right now it only shows the last question for all of the text fields.

I also tried using an index with each_with_index and each.with_index but I couldn't get that to work.

How do I get it to:

1. Display the correct question for each text field.
2. include the story_question_id for each text field when saved.

[image: Story Controller]

[image: Story Form]

[image: Story Page]

[image: Story Model]

[image: Story Answer Model]

[image: Story Question Model]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your print screen of the form is not sufficient, as it only shows the answers for each question, which doesn't help a lot.

First you should add this relation

```
class Story
  has_many :story_questions
```

Then add this to your form:

```
<%= @story.story_questions.each do |question| %>
```

From here you can do it two ways. Either create a new form within the loop for the answer, or add a custom `f.input` field for each of the questions you loop trough. Then in the backend manually loop trough the params and create the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the controller and form code to the following and now I am able to display the correct questions for each answer field. I was also able to add the question ID to the hidden field to solve the second issue.

[image: Story Controller]

[image: Story Form]

[image: Story Page]